# How to Select the current class of DIV

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, class, html

I am assigning the unique ids to the `div` by selecting their class

```
$("#addTab").live('click', function() {
    index++;
    var title = 'Tab.....  ' + index;
    var url = '#fragment-' + index;

    addTab(url, title, index);
    $('li.ui-state-default:last').attr("id",index); // How I can get the current class??

});
```

But I want to assign these ids to current tab. coz last tab is not getting the id

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ranasaani/DsA8T/1/

Comment: I want to select the current class

Comment: The  current is the active, right?

Comment: no its not necessary.. cause tabs are creating on the basis of data from database and I want to assign each tab a unique id at that time by their class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('li.ui-state-default:last').attr('class');
```

every selected tab has class `ui-selected`, `ui-state-focus` and `ui-state-active`

So you can get class like

```
$('li.ui-selected').attr('class');
```

To get class of newly added tab try:

```
var ref = $('li.ui-state-default:last').attr("id",index); 
alert($(ref).attr('class'));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/VX2Q9/2/)**

Comment: It changes the id of whole class

Comment: @RanaSaani do you wanna assign id to selected tab or newly added tab?